# wx.ListCtrl and column header tooltips

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm looking for a way to show tooltips whenever the user hovers the
mouse on a column header of a wx.ListCtrl, is this possible?
I tried binding `wx.EVT_MOTION` but it looks like it works only for the
list items, not the headers.. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

(wxPython 2.8.9.1 on Xubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible at the present moment, the EVT_MOTION only picks up coords via GetPosition() when you are within the list itself, the columns do not appear to register a coord when you hover over them.

I was able to find this [link](http://hg.wxpython.org/hg/wxPy-trunk/rev/57b2f6a61a20) where it appears they are working on such ability in wx.lib.agw.UltimateListCtrl, you might want to ask on the wxpython mailing list to see if/when this feature might be released.

Comment: search for **def SetColumnToolTip(self, col, tip)** within the link above ;)

Comment: Fyi, I checked out the latest version of the agw module, it appears the SetColumnToolTip function has already been added. :D You can download it [here](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/index.html).

Comment: For reference, AGW is included in wxPython since 2.8.9.2, while UltimateListCtrl is present since 2.8.11.0. SetColumnToolTip appears in 2.8.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this for column headers, but this works for individual cells:

```
    self.lc = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
    # ...
    self.lc.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)

def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
    pos = self.lc.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
    item_index, flag = self.lc.HitTest(pos)
    tip = self.lc.GetToolTip()

    if flag == wx.LIST_HITTEST_ONITEMLABEL:
        tip.SetTip('Some information about ' + self.lc.GetItemText(item_index))
    else:
        tip.SetTip('')

    evt.Skip()
```

It doesn't dispatch the event when I hover over column headers, at least not on my PC (Win 10).

I found this answer here: https://coderedirect.com/questions/378870/how-to-tweak-my-tooltips-in-wxpython.